# D3.js - Fading in data points sequentially

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

I've just started learning d3. I've made some progress on learning, but I've run into something I haven't been able to figure out on my own.

Here is what I have so far: http://tributary.io/inlet/83fba4500986b4638326

What I've been trying to figure out how to do is fade in the data points as the line path animates through them. The best idea I had was dividing the transition time by the number of points and then have the delay for each data point be decided by that, but I had trouble getting that working properly.

Is there a reasonable way to do this?

P.S. I also seem to have lost my y-axis labels and am not sure why... any ideas?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

So let's start by the easy part. The Y axis is missing because your svg elements have an overflow:hidden and the second svg element is stuck to the top left of corner of the first one. some x,y space plus overflow:auto solve the problem.

For fading the circle when the path go trought it, I don't think you can do that with one transition. So, a solution, because the path drawing works on offset from total length to 0, you can calculate the distance between each circle and "transition" the path from circle to circle, fading it at the end of the transition. To do so, get the circles coordinates, calculate the distances, and set the transition loop.

```
//Get coordinates
svg.selectAll("circle").each(function(){
  coordinates.push({x:d3.select(this).attr("cx"),y:d3.select(this).attr("cy")});
  });

//Get Distances
 for(var j=0;j<coordinates.length-2;j++)
  {
    var a,b,distance;
    a= coordinates[j];
    b= coordinates[j+1];
    distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b.x-a.x,2))+(Math.pow(b.y-a.y,2)));
    //console.log("j:" + j + " a: " + JSON.stringify(a) + " b: " + JSON.stringify(b) + " distance: " +  distance);
    distanceData.push(distance)
  }



//Loop transition
var counterTransition =0,currentLength=distanceData[counterTransition];


        path
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
        .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .ease("cubic")
          .attr("stroke-dashoffset",totalLength-currentLength)
        .attr("class", "line").each("end",animeNext);

  function animeNext(){
    counterTransition +=1;
    if(counterTransition<=distanceData.length)
    {
      var circle =svg.selectAll("circle")[0][counterTransition];
      circle=d3.select(circle);
      circle.attr("opacity",0.5);
      currentLength +=  distanceData[counterTransition]  ;
      path
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease("cubic")
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset",totalLength - currentLength)
      .attr("class", "line").each("end",animeNext);; 
    }
```

Example : http://tributary.io/inlet/e2eab2e689479008f11c

I simplified the data generation for the sake of the test. Removed the draw on click. It looks like that the code executes 1 to 3 times randomly but I think it is tributary.
You can play with the duration to improve transition smoothness.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Other solution with one transition, using a short interval(100ms) and checking if the path's stroke-dashoffset is equal or greater than each circle's distance and if so fade the circle. Clear the interval at the end of the transition.